# "Add To Pocket" as text and not image

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, pocket

Unlike [Instapaper](https://www.instapaper.com/publishers), [Pocket](http://getpocket.com/publisher/button) does not offer publishers a way to add an "Add to Pocket" **text** anchor.

This is the code I gather I should put in my index:

```
 <a href="https://getpocket.com/save" class="pocket-btn" data-lang="en"
 data-save-url="http://yourDomain.com/the/page/to/save.html"
 data-pocket-count="vertical" 
 data-pocket-align="left"
 >Pocket</a>
 <script type="text/javascript">!function(d,i){if(!d.getElementById(i)){var j=d.createElement("script");j.id=i;j.src="https://widgets.getpocket.com/v1/j/btn.js?v=1";var w=d.getElementById(i);d.body.appendChild(j);}}(document,"pocket-btn-js");</script>
```

I'm using WordPress, so I'll have to replace the `data-save-url` with PHP, that's not a problem. The problem is that I can't figure out how to make this element appear as Text *and* work properly. I've tried hiding its `img` class and using `span` and `content:before/after`, but it doesn't work as the Javascript code is executing *after* the CSS has already loaded (?).

Comment: I don't see how you can, as the button is in an iframe. Here is a fidddle for others who want a go. http://jsfiddle.net/e028gb4j/

Answer (score 1):

had the same problem. After a little search I used:

```
<a href="https://getpocket.com/edit.php?url=http://www.example.com/myPage.html">Save to Pocket</a>
```

You will be loosing the counter though. And of course a user must be logged in to Pocket to save immediately, if not he will be redirected to login page. 
This worked fine for me. Hope it does for you too.